# How to make GridList face vertically in One Row with React and materialUI on Mobile

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

How do I make Materia-UI GridList Face vertically in One Row on Mobile?
My GridList is two in a row which is what I wanted but when I inspect it on mobile it still shows two in a row instead of One. that means it's not responsive, How do I make it responsive?

this is my Events Component.

```
import React from "react";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

import GridList from "@material-ui/core/GridList";
import GridListTile from "@material-ui/core/GridListTile";
import GridListTileBar from "@material-ui/core/GridListTileBar";
import ListSubheader from "@material-ui/core/ListSubheader";
mport IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = (theme) => ({
 root: {
  display: "flex",
  flexWrap: "wrap",
  justifyContent: "space-around",
  overflow: "hidden",
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
},
gridList: {
  width: 1000,
  height: 950,
},
icon: {
  color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)",
},
});

class EventsList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { events: [] };
}

componentDidMount() {
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:9000/events/")
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({ events: response.data });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

render() {
const { classes } = this.props;
return (
  <div className={classes.root}>
    <GridList cellHeight={330} className={classes.gridList} spacing={8}>
      <GridListTile key="Subheader" cols={2} style={{ height: "auto" }}>
        <ListSubheader component="div">December</ListSubheader>
      </GridListTile>
      {this.state.events.map((tile) => (
        <GridListTile key={tile.eventImage}>
          <img src={tile.eventImage} alt={tile.title} />
          <GridListTileBar title={tile.title} titlePosition="top" />

          <GridListTileBar
            paragraph={tile.description}
            actionIcon={
              <IconButton
                aria-label={`info about ${tile.title}`}
                className={classes.icon}
              ></IconButton>
            }
          />
        </GridListTile>
      ))}
    </GridList>
  </div>
);
 }
}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(EventsList);
```

this is the List of my events displayed by GridList on Mobile
[image: Thsi is what GridList is Giving me]

but something like this is what I want to see when I am on Mobile.[image: Tshis is what I want to see on Mobile]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using class based component, you can use [withWidth](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#withwidth) to conditionally set `cols` value to `GridList`.

See [working example here in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-image-grid-list-withwidth-oheez?file=/src/imageList.js)

**Example code snippet**

```js
class TitlebarGridList extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes, width } = this.props; // <---- see here
    let columns = width === "xs" || width === "sm" ? 1 : 2;
    console.log("=========>", width);
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <GridList cellHeight={200} className={classes.gridList} cols={columns}>  {/* //<---- see here */}
          <GridListTile key="Subheader" cols={3} style={{ height: "auto" }}>
            <ListSubheader component="div">December</ListSubheader>
          </GridListTile>
          {tileData.map(tile => (
            <GridListTile key={tile.title}>
              <img className={classes.image} src={tile.img} alt={tile.title} />
            </GridListTile>
          ))}
        </GridList>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TitlebarGridList.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default compose(
  withStyles(styles, {
    name: "TitlebarGridList"
  }),
  withWidth() //<---- see here
)(TitlebarGridList);
```

Note: `withWidth` will be deprecated sometime in the future, so consider to use [useMediaQuery hook](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/#using-material-uis-breakpoint-helpers) (in that case you have to switch to functional component).